# How to save web service response (a byte array) as a file using SOAP UI?

Tags: arrays, soapui

I am using SOAP UI 3.0.1 for testing my web service which returns a byte array. I want to save the byte array as a word file. How do I accomplish it using Groovy Script or any other way?
The web service response is,

   
               0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPgADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAA...............................

Answer (score 3):

Bingo!!

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context );
filename = groovyUtils.projectPath + "\\" +System.currentTimeMillis()+ ".doc"
def objFile = new java.io.File(filename)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder('GetDocument#Response');
holder.declareNamespace('ns1','Utlities.Service.Documents');
def byteArray = holder.getNodeValue("//ns1:GetDocumentResponse[1]/ns1:GetDocumentResult" )
def b64 = new Base64()
def textBytes = b64.decode(byteArray.getBytes())
FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(objFile);
fos.write( textBytes );
fos.flush();
fos.close();
log.info("Output file: " + filename)
```